# Obtaining unique list using set function with multiple elements

Tags: python, list, set

Two part question from someone quite new to python (and scripting in general):

I've worked out how to get a list of IP addresses from a file, then output a unique set of those IPs to a file as follows:

```
ip_list = []

with open('testfile', 'r') as file:
  for line in file:
    if line not in ip_list:
      ip_list.append(line)

with open('testoutput', 'w') as file:
  for line in ip_list:
    file.write("%s\n" % line)
```

I then saw that I could do this an alternate way, and I'm wondering if this is sane?

```
ip_list = []

with open('testfile', 'r') as file:
  for line in file:
    ip_list.append(line)

with open('testoutput', 'w') as file:
  for line in set(ip_list):
    file.write("%s\n" % line)
```

Next, I now want to get a list of IP addresses coupled with PERMIT/DENY strings, given that the opened file is something like:

```
1.1.1.1 PERMIT
2.2.2.2 PERMIT
3.3.3.3 DENY
1.1.1.1 PERMIT
```

I still want to output only the unique IPs, so I can do this with the first method:

```
 ip_list = []

 with open('testfile', 'r') as file:
   for line in file:
     elements = line.split(' ')
     if elements[0] not in ip_list
       ip_list.append(elements)

 with open('testoutput', 'w') as file:
   for line in ip_list:
     file.write("%s %s\n" % (line[0], line[1]))
```

But can I do something using the set command instead?  Or can I do something better than the above snippet?
And for this example, assume that I don't want to compare entire lines for uniqueness (i.e. '1.1.1.1 PERMIT')

Comment: In your 2nd example it's more efficient to just use a set to store the lines rather than storing them in a list that gets converted to a set. Bear in mind that sets have no inherent order, so to preserve order you may wish to maintain a list and a set, as in Tom Karzes's answer. Alternatively, you can convert the final set back into a list and sort it before printing.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like:

```
ip_set = set()
ip_list = []

with open('testfile', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        elements = line.split()
        ip = elements[0]
        if ip not in ip_set
            ip_set.add(ip)
            ip_list.append(elements)

with open('testoutput', 'w') as file:
    for line in ip_list:
        file.write("%s %s\n" % (line[0], line[1]))
```

Note that I removed the argument to `split()`, so that it will handle all whitespace, not just spaces.